# Problema de compatibilidade com áudio API firefox

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

Estou usando a *API* para emitir alguns sons, o problema é que no *Firefox* eu não consigo rodar *mp3*, mas como eu posso fazer para incluir outra formatação nesse código?

Como eu posso fazer para adicionar outra fonte *ogg* por exemplo?

Estou usando API para chamar o Audio assim:

```
 var SomDeDigito = new Audio('sounds/keyboard.mp3');
 var SomDeError = new Audio('sounds/erro.mp3');
 var SomDeSky = new Audio('sounds/sky.mp3');
 var SomDeEstrela = new Audio('sounds/estrela.mp3');
 var SomDeSkyFall = new Audio('sounds/skyFall.mp3');

function digito(){
    SomDeDigito.pause();
    SomDeDigito.currentTime = 0;
    SomDeDigito.play();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O suporte da API Audio no Firefox é, no momento, parcial, como você pode ver [nesta lista da fundação Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility):

```
<audio>: MP3    Firefox (Gecko): Partial (see below)
```

> To avoid patent issues, support for MPEG 4, H.264, MP3 and AAC is not built directly into Firefox on desktop and mobile (Android and Firefox OS). Instead it relies on support from the OS or hardware (the hardware also needs to be able to support the profile used to encode the video, in the case of MP4).

A tradução em Português é a seguinte:

> Para evitar questões de patentes, o suporte para MPEG 4, H.264, MP3 and AAC não são construidas diretamente no Firefox desktop e em dispositivos móveis (Android e Firefox OS). Ao invés disso ele conta com o apoio do sistema operacional ou hardware (o hardware também precisa ser capaz de suportar o perfil usado para codificar o vídeo, no caso do MP4).

No seu caso, seria aconselhável permitir a seleção do formato a ser consumido de acordo com o cliente - ou converter sua base de arquivos para formato Ogg Vorbis, já que todos os browsers modernos suportam este formato.

Answer (score 2):

Use o SoundManager 2, é uma API híbrida muito boa, que usa um player em Flash quando não há suporte total ao HTML5.

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Comment: Eu realmente gostei dessa lib, mas não é muito simples ):
estou buscando a melhor alternativa nativa possível.